# how to put data from a text file into array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to put data from a text file into an array. below is the array i am trying to create.

```
 [("major",r,w,w,s,w,w,w,s), ("relative minor",r,w,s,w,w,s,w,w),
  ("harmonic minor",r,w,s,w,w,s,w+s,s)]
```

But instead when i use the text file and load the data from it I get below as my output. it should output as above, i realise i have to split it but i dont really know how for this sort of set array. could anyone help me with this

```
['("major",r,w,w,s,w,w,w,s), ("relative minor",r,w,s,w,w,s,w,w), 
 ("harmonic minor",r,w,s,w,w,s,w+s,s)']
```

below is my text file I am trying to load.

```
("major",r,w,w,s,w,w,w,s), ("relative minor",r,w,s,w,w,s,w,w), ("harmonic minor",r,w,s,w,w,s,w+s,s)
```

And this is how im loading it

```
file = open("slide.txt", "r")

scale = [file.readline()]
```

Comment: ARe `r`, `w` and `s` defined in your code somewhere? If they aren't you are going to have to leave them as strings.

Comment: yes they are defined at the top of the code, i didnt put them in her though

Comment: Can you put that in. It's a pretty important part of getting this working.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a `list` instead of an `array`:

```
     with open(filename) as f:
          list_name = f.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

Some questions come to mind about what the rest of your implementation looks like and how you figure it all will work, but below is an example of how this could be done in a pretty straight forward way:

```
class W(object):
    pass


class S(object):
    pass


class WS(W, S):
    pass


class R(object):
    pass


def main():
    # separate parts that should become tuples eventually
    text = str()
    with open("data", "r") as fh:
        text = fh.read()
    parts = text.split("),")

    # remove unwanted characters and whitespace
    cleaned = list()
    for part in parts:
        part = part.replace('(', '')
        part = part.replace(')', '')
        cleaned.append(part.strip())

    # convert text parts into tuples with actual data types
    list_of_tuples = list()
    for part in cleaned:
        t = construct_tuple(part)
        list_of_tuples.append(t)

    # now use the data for something
    print list_of_tuples


def construct_tuple(data):
    t = tuple()
    content = data.split(',')
    for item in content:
        t = t + (get_type(item),)
    return t


# there needs to be some way to decide what type/object should be used:
def get_type(id):
    type_mapping = {
        '"harmonic minor"': 'harmonic minor',
        '"major"': 'major',
        '"relative minor"': 'relative minor',
        's': S(),
        'w': W(),
        'w+s': WS(),
        'r': R()
    }
    return type_mapping.get(id)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This code makes some assumptions:

- there is a file `data` with the content:

  ```
  ("major",r,w,w,s,w,w,w,s), ("relative minor",r,w,s,w,w,s,w,w), ("harmonic minor",r,w,s,w,w,s,w+s,s)
  ```
- you want a list of tuples which contains the values.
- It's acceptable to have `w+s` represented by some data type, as it would be difficult to have something like `w+s` appear inside a tuple without it being evaluated when the tuple is created. Another way to do it would be to have `w` and `s` represented by data types that can be used with `+`.

So even if this works, it might be a good idea to think about the format of the text file (if you have control of that), and see if it can be changed into something which would allow you to use some parsing library in a simple way, e.g. see how it could be more easily represented as csv or even turn it into json.